# Batch change of field value in Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

For a charity, I've set up a mailing list with some customised fields. One of these fields has a default value, and updated values for individual subscribers. However, I now have to reset the field for all subscribers to a new default value, and this will need to be done again on a yearly basis.
The only way I found to do this so far is to delete the field and recreate it with the new default value. But this is very sensitive to errors when I transfer the management to other volunteers.
Is there an easier way to achieve a field value reset in Mailchimp?

In addition, I'm looking to update a field value for a subset of subscribers in batch. If possible, the solution applies to this problem as well.

Thanks, Juul.

Answer (score 3):

You can export the contacts list following these steps:
https://mailchimp.com/en/help/view-or-export-a-list/

Then make the changes you need in the exported list.

Finally, import it again checking the field "Update existing contacts":
https://mailchimp.com/help/import-contacts-mailchimp

Comment: The import help link has expired - I am not sure this is possible any more.